# ipython -c broken in 0.11?

Tags: python, ipython

I used to be able to start ipython from the command line like so:

```
ipython -c 'print "Hi"'
```

or more usefully

```
ipython -i -pdb -c "%run my_program.py"
```

Now I get the error: `[TerminalIPythonApp] Unrecognized flag: '-c'`.

Is this an ipython-0.11 bug or is the capability being 'phased out'?  Or, better yet, am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this an issue in the argument parsing in 0.11.  It requires that you specify anything that takes a value with '=', so it must be:

```
ipython --c='print "Hi"'
```

This requirement has been relaxed in [git master](https://github.com/ipython/ipython), and your command as-written* will work in 0.12, out later this month.

* only one-character flags allow a single `-`, longer ones require leading `--`, so it would have to be:

```
ipython -i --pdb -c "%run my_program.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ipython --c='print "Hi"'` works for me.

See `ipython -h`

> --c= (InteractiveShellApp.code_to_run)
>       Default: ''
>       Execute the given command string.